# Faces shading looks strangely segmented after extrusions

Tags: shaders, shadows

I extruded something from this Obj model and the shading looks segmented as if there were distinct models.

I have already checked that my normals are not inside out.

[image: weird shading after extruding]

Normals look ok:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is that you extruded faces which edges were marked as sharp (hence the light blue lines), so the extruded geometry kept those properties.

To fix that, select the concerned edges in `Edit Mode`, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>E</kbd> and use `Clear Sharp` function:

[image: demo gif]

Comment: it helps to fix the problem but it still has this strange shading to it...like a silver metal look

Comment: here is the picture     https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/123671/strange-shading-part-2

Answer (score 0):

It'd help if you could post your blend file, but what I suspect from looking at the images is that you have duplicate verts or faces.  See if you have faces inside that shape, or select all of the vertices and use Mesh -> Vertices -> Remove Doubles.

Comment: sorry I already tried that