# Strange Shading Part 2

Tags: modeling, mesh, faces, topology

The problem from my [previous question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/123592/faces-shading-looks-strangely-segmented-after-extrusions) is partly fixed, it still has a strange shading to it

[image]

[image]

Comment: As I mentioned in the other question, it'd be WAY easier for someone to help you if you posted your .blend file.  If you're concerned about someone stealing your model, just cut out the badly shaded part and upload that piece.

Comment: Is this shading problem visible in the final rendering?

Comment: it looks like you have smoothed your object (T panel > Tools > Shading > Smooth) but, as it has not enough faces, it creates this sort of shades. If so (?) you can artificially increase the topology with a Subdivision Surface modifier (Subdivisions of 2), but you may need to create additional edges to sharp some angles.

Comment: Adding geometry to fix the shading is not the best option. Use the shading tools first.

Comment: This isn't adequate as a question; I don't know what you're trying to model, what it is that you think is wrong with your shading, or really anything at all about the problem. Hyperlinking to another question doesn't help it. Please consider setting up a detailed question and, if relevant, at least screen-shotting your shader graph so people can tell you more about why it's behaving the way it is. As it is, I've flagged the question for moderator attention.

Comment: @MichaelMacha The guy asking this question over three years ago hasn't been very active since then, I doubt your comment will be read by him anyway.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Yikes. I saw the low quality and assumed it was recent. This really doesn't belong here.

Answer (score 1):

Now it's exactly the inverse problem from before. You used to have to prevent edges from being sharp, now you need to mark some sharp edges so they don't appear smooth.

You can do this the same way before, selection the edges supposed to be sharp, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> → Mark sharp. The issue with this method is that you need to do this everywhere needed; It's quite long to do.

Fortunately, you can let the software do most of the work for you; Since the idea is to mark sharp when some faces do a certain angle, you can go to the Data tab of your object, and find the Auto Smooth option in the Normals tab :

[image]

The way it works is simple. Once enable it smoothes the whole mesh, but mark as sharp every edge forming at least the angle specified below. I use 66 usually, it's a nice value; You can adapt this to your need.

(Also, all the sharp marked edges only work with auto smooth enabled).

Comment: it doesn't work it becomes segmented again when I tried this

Comment: what do you mean "segmented"? Images are worth thousands of words.